# jPlayer pause button is display inline but should be block

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jplayer

I use the jPlayer jquery-ui theme: http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-07

When i click the pause button on my player the button shows the "pause" title and the pause icon is not showing. The icon should be placed by jquery-ui classes: *ui-icon ui-icon-pause*

While comparing it to the original from the link above i noticed that in the a element the "display: none" inline style is replaced by `display: inline`.
In the original it is replaced by `display: block`

```
<a title="pause" tabindex="2" class="jp-pause ui-icon ui-icon-pause" href="javascript:;" style="display: none;">pause</a>
```

Fixing this in Firebug the icon renders correct.

So why does it replace the `display: none` with `display: inline` instead of `display: block` in my player when clicking the pause button?

I guess jPlayer uses hide() & show() of jquery for switching the buttons.

Answer (score 4):

I have just battled my way through the same issue with Jplayer. Your initial comment above was 100% correct, the jquery show() method assigns an inline style. Here is the fix:

1. Go to the developers website and download the latest un-minified source code - [Jplayer Download area](http://www.jplayer.org/download/)
2. Open this file jquery.jplayer.js and find line 1621
3. Do the following change

Faulty Code:

```
this.css.jq.pause.show();
```

Change to (working):

```
this.css.jq.pause.css("display", "block");
```

Awesome, hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks for that, i wonder if this is a bug in jPlayer, if so it should be official fixed. Or is it a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue was caused by delaying stylesheets to load. 
Make sure to have loaded skin styles before initializing the player.

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried to add `display: block;` in the pause button styles. Only that makes the pause button flash on load. So that was not a good solution.

Searching with Google, I found out that one way to fix the problem is to change the anchor with a division as in:

Inline Version:

```
<a href="#" class="jp-play">Play</a>
<a href="#" class="jp-pause">Pause</a>
```

Block Version:

```
<div class="jp-play">Play</div>
<div class="jp-pause">Pause</div>
```

Then the pause button appears as a block as expected.

Source: https://karolo.com/blog/developer/jplayer-how-to-use-jplayer-to-build-your-own-mp3-player.html